# Avoid declare a variable first when filling it

Tags: javascript, variables, design-patterns

**Disclaimer:** This is more a question about design patterns rather than a case study one.

I'm very sure that I can explain it better with an example:

```
var arrayToFill = [];
    for(var key in obj)
        arrayToFill.push(obj[key]);
```

Is there a way that I can do it without declare `arrayToFill` in another line? Or, if not, any good pattern to achieve a better code?

EDIT: So fusspots... I change `products` by `arraToFill` but I think a brained human could understand the question.

Comment: Why would you want to obscure something that is simple and explicit?

Comment: Because I think the empty declaration it's not explanatory, doesn't matter what if since it's filled. However, I'm just looking for something different, maybe doesn't exists ;)

Comment: `arrayToFill` is not used in the code.

Comment: I have no clue what your example is explaining better... An unused declared array?

Comment: @Bursos I think you've got your code snippet wrong. `products` should be `arrayToFill`

Comment: @jasonscript you're right, I modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience what you have in your example is the best pattern.

In the following example, where `arrayToFill` is not declared within the function, a globally scoped variable will be automatically created

```
function ScopeExample (){
  for(var key in obj)
    arrayToFill.push(obj[key]);     // arrayToFill not previously declared
}
```

results in

```
var arrayToFill;                    // automatically created
function ScopeExample (){
  for(var key in obj)
    arrayToFill.push(obj[key]);     // arrayToFill not previously declared
}
```

In my opinion, most (all?) developers will understand the code snippet that you have in your question without any problems.

Comment: Woooha! Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for! I'm gonna test what kind of types supports that syntaxis. Thanks again @jasonscript !

Comment: Just to be clear, implicit globals like in the first snippet of this answer are almost universally considered to be a bad thing. Don't do that.

Comment: @Bursos I agree with ohlec. **Not declaring your variables is a bad thing** - it's much easier to understand code if the variables are all explicitly defined